# Command-line properties file reference overriding mule-app.xml

Tags: mule

I have placed variables in a few *.properties* files and have successfully created a *mule.env* variable in mule's *mule-app.properties* file to reference which of those files to use. I am trying to allow a command-line argument override the *mule.env* variable so that a specified properties file can be used. I also like having the *mule.env* variable exist in *mule-app.properties* file as a default value in case nothing is set via the command-line. But it seems that the existing *mule-app.properties* file overrides the command-line argument.

The mule-app.parameters file contains a variable like this:

```
mule.env=dev
```

While a command-line argument looks like this:

```
-Dmule.env=prod
```

A property placeholder looks for the properties file like so:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:${mule.env}.properties" />
```

The result that I prefer is that the property placeholder finds the prod.properties file rather than the dev.properties file when the mule app starts with the command line argument; however, it still uses the dev.properties file.

If I remove the variable from the *mule-app.properties* file, the command-line argument works fine.

I prefer that the command-line overrides the what is in the *mule-app.properties* file. Is that possible? What have I done incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose You have to set the property in the Mule `wrapper.conf`:

1. Navigate to `[Mule standalone]/conf` folder.
2. Open `wrapper.conf` in a any text editor.
3. Add the following script under `# GC settings`: `wrapper.java.additional.15=-­Denv=prod`

Notes: make sure the number is correct. In this example the last number in that file is: wrapper.java.additional.**14**